# How to insert HTML into getDocumentByID.innerHTML function

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am writing a function to insert a clock countdown that outputs the hour and minutes until something happens. However, I want to customize the HTML of the hour and minutes variables to appear within  tags. So far this is what I have:

```
var hours = math for hours goes here;
var minutes = math for minutes goes here;

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = hours + "hrs"
+ minutes + "min";
```

I'm not sure how to add an HTML tag around the hours and minutes elements. Essentially I want it to output as

```
<span>12hrs</span>
<span>50min</span>
```

I have the variable time math working but just need to get some html span classes in there.

Thanks for any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 5):

You can just normally add the strings

```js
let hours = 20
let minutes = 7

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<span>" + hours + "hrs" + "</span><span>" + minutes + "min"+ "</span>";
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Or in these case make use of [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which allows you to interpolate expressions inside string. Actually it prevents user to use `+`

```js
let hours = 20
let minutes = 7
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = `<span>${hours}hrs</span><span>${minutes}min</span>`;
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Or create a function which return text inside `<span>`

```js
let hours = 20
let minutes = 7

const span = (text) => `<span>${text}</span>`
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = `${span(hours+"hrs")}${span(minutes+"mins")}`;
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: I removed my downvote. I originally downvoted since it was the exact same as my answer which was before. Now I see you added something else

Answer (score 2):

You can put the `<span>` in strings.

```
var hours = math for hours goes here;
var minutes = math for minutes goes here;

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<span>" + hours + "hrs" + "</span>" + "<span>" + minutes + "min" + "</span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ES6 [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
var hours = 12;
var minutes = 50;
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = `<span>${hours}hrs</span><span>${minutes}min</span>`;
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```